# A proof of the existence of real root for odd degree real polynomials by induction

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

After thinking over the flaw in my argument of regarding the proof that [every odd degree polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401059/is-my-proof-for-the-existence-of-roots-of-an-odd-degree-polynomial-correct), I started devising another proof. The brief idea of the proof is as follows.

Suppose that $f$ be a polynomial with real coefficients where $f(0)\ne0$, let, $$P(n):= \deg{f}=2n+1\implies \exists \alpha_{2n+1},\beta_{2n+1}\in\mathbb{R}\mid (f(x)<0\ \forall x\le\phi_{2n+1})\land(f(x)>0\ \forall x\ge\psi_{2n+1})$$

**Base Case:** $P(0)$ is trivially true.

**Induction Step:** So, we assume that for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $P(i)$ is true for all $i$ such that $0\le i\le k$. To prove $P(k+1)$ let $f$ be an arbitrary polynomial of degree $2(k+1)+1$, i.e., $2k+3$, say, $$f(x)=a_{2k+3}x^{2k+3}+a_{2k+2}x^{2k+2}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$Now let $x^{2i+1}$ the term with non zero coefficient for some $i$ such that $0\le i\le k$ (if $i=k+1$ then the case is trivial). Then we rewrite $f(x)$ as, \begin{align}f(x)&=x^{2i+2}\left(a_{2k+3}x^{2(k-i)+1}+a_{2k+2}x^{2(k-i)}+\ldots+a_{2i+2}\right)+\left(a_{2i+1}x^{2i+1}+\ldots+a_0\right)\\&=g(x)+h(x)\end{align}Now since $\deg g,\deg h\le 2k+1$, by induction hypothesis we conclude that $f(x)<0$ for all $x<\min \left(\phi_{2(k-i)+1},\phi_{2i+1}\right)$.

Similar argument holds for $f(x)>0$.

Comment: Already the base case is false. And, please, don't put $\forall $ behind the formula it generalizes

Comment: "$P(0)$ is trivially true": actually it's trivially false $-$ $f(x)=-x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @TonyK There are many more counterexmples. In fact there are *only* counterexamples

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: oh yes, you're right $-$ I didn't notice the misprint "$<$" for "$>$". But it's even false modulo this misprint :-)

Comment: Thanks for noting the typo. I think that it is alright now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not proving the existence of a root, but of values where the polynomial is positive (negative).

The proof assumes there exists a nonzero odd coefficient below the highest degree term, which is not correct.  For instance $x^5 - x^4 + 1$ does not inductively reduce to anything of degree $3$ or $1$.

Call an odd degree polynomial "sign controlled" if there is a constant $c$ such that the sign of $p(x)$ is the same as the sign of its highest degree monomial whenever $|x|>c$.  Your argument is that sign-controlled polynomials are closed under the following operations:

- multiplication by $x^2$ (doing this several times multiplies by $x^{2k}$)
- multiplication by a nonzero constant
- addition of polynomials whose highest-degree coefficients **have the same sign.**

and you hope to generate any odd degree polynomial by those operations from polynomials of degree $1$, which are sign controlled.

But these operations can only produce polynomials whose nonzero odd degree coefficients are all of the same sign.  It is not possible to produce polynomials such as $x^3 - x$, so this method will not show that they have the right signs for large values of $|x|$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: The difficulty that arises from your first example can be removed if we consider $g(x)=x^5-x^4-x+1$ and I didn't think about the examples of the last type because in this case $f(0)=0$.

Comment: If you mean writing  x^5 - x^4 + 1 = g(x) + x , note that there isn't any way for the operations used in your proof to validate the theorem for g(x), because the x^5 and x^1 terms don't have the same sign.   It's not hard to prove what I wrote at the last paragraph, that all the operations preserve the property that odd degree coefficients of a polynomial all have the same sign, so one cannot prove the theorem this way for a polynomial with both positive and negative odd degree coefficients.   This $g(x)$ is also an example with nonzero constant term.

Comment: When I asked about an inductive proof of the fact to one of my professor then (after seeing my argument) he suggested to consider the set of all polynomials of degree $n$ with positive leading coefficient. Let the set be $\mathfrak{P}$. Then, we write, $P(n):=f\in\mathfrak{P}\land \deg f=2n+1$ implies that for all $\varepsilon>0, f(x)>\varepsilon$ forall sufficiently large positive $x$ and $f(x)<-\varepsilon$ forall sufficiently small negative $x$. Now $P(0)$ is true and so we assume that for some $k\ge 0$, $P(i)$ is true for all $0\le i\le k$. ...

Comment: ...Now we claim that, if $g$ be a polynomial of degree $2k+2$ then for all $\delta>0$ there  exists $\theta>0$ that $f(x)>\delta$ for all $x$ such that $|x|>\theta$. From this claim the rest part follows trivially.

Comment: It still does not work.  The problem with the induction argument was the lack of dependence on the coefficients of the polynomial and this is still the case in the new argument that also tries to prove the analogous statement for odd degrees.   If all you get to use is that $P_n(x)$ has the correct sign for large |x|, the argument would work for any linear combination of non-polynomial functions with the same sign patterns on the same intervals, which is not the case.

Comment: I don't understand the last line of your comment. Can you explain that a bit? However, notice that I am not using that "$P_n(x)$ has the correct sign for large $|x|$". Rather, what I am using is "$P_{2k+2}(x)$ has the correct sign for large $|x|$ where the leading coefficient of $P_{2k+2}(x)$ is positive".

Comment: More specifically, can you produce a counterexample?

Comment: The new proof is just strengthening the induction hypothesis.  You might as well go all the way and try and prove inductively that any polynomial $P(x)$ has the same sign as its highest degree term, for $|x|>C_P$.  And you will still run into the problem that trying to simplify the polynomial by reducing some lower degree terms to their signs (that are determined by the induction hypothesis) loses control over the magnitude of these terms, which depend on the coefficients.  There are ways of correcting that but they will tend to rewrite your proof as the standard non-inductive proof.